# Ansible: using nested groups with vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a situation where we have 3 tiers of boxes, in each tier we apply different variables settings (like where the cache dir is), but there are a bunch of defaults. I also need to override on a *per node* basis, which is usually done via inventory vars on the host itself. I am not sure what is the best way to organize the hosts so that the [precedence works](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) in my favor.

Here are the different things I have tried. In each case I have entries in the inventory file like this:

```
[bots-fancy]
fancy-1 

[bots-super-fancy]
super-1

[bots-magical]
magic-1
magic-2 provider=aws
```

At first, I had each of them with a long string of variable definitions. I also had different `group_var/bots/[bots-magical | bots-super-fancy | bots-fancy].yaml` files. This quickly became untenable.

---

attempt 1: with playbook variables
In the playbook I had something like this:

```
---
hosts:
  - bots
vars_files:
  - "group_vars/bots/defaults.yml"
  - "group_vars/bots/{{ groups_names[0] }}.yml"
roles:
  - somethign
```

this worked (though yes brittle) but it wouldn't let me override on a *per host* basis. I had to set things different on nodes occasionally, but not on the whole group.

---

attempt 2: using `group_vars` for each

I added

```
[bots:children]
bots-fancy
bots-super-fancy
bots-magical
```

to the hosts file. Removed any `vars_files` from the playbook and created `group_vars` for each group. I added the default/shared settings to `group_vars/bots.yaml`. When I'd run the playbook, it would only load the `bots` group_vars it seemed. Ideally, I want it to load the `bots` and then override it with the `bots-fancy`. And then finally the values from the hosts file.

I am not sure the best way to structure these groups, so any input would be very helpful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what is your problem. You should be fine with:

hosts:

```
[bots-a]
bot1

[bots-b]
bot2

[bots:children]
bots-a
bots-b
```

dirs:

```
./group_vars/bots.yml
./group_vars/bots-a.yml
./group_vars/bots-b.yml
```

There is a concept of group depth in Ansible (at least in recent versions). In this example, group variables for host `bot2` will be populated in the following order:

depth 0: group `all`, `all.yml` (missing here, ignoring)
depth 1: group `bots`, `bots.yml`
depth 2: group `bots-b`, `bots-b.yml`

You can see details and processing order [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/vars/__init__.py#L250) in the source code.

So if you define defaults in `bots.yml` and specific values in `bots-b.yml`, you should achieve what you expect.