# Ansible nested loops through inventories

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I was looking at the Loops page of Ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html but I could not find what I am looking for...

I would like to test if a "source" host can reach / connect to a set of target hosts on a set of ports. Each set of target host can be, for example, an inventory group and each inventory group has a list of their own ports to be tested.

The idea is to specify only two vars as input to the playbook: a list of groups of hosts and a list of one or more source hosts.

How the loop should be done? The inventory can be YAML or INI files: one or multiple, for each group. The test of a TCP connection is easy... so the focus is only on the input vars and loop construction.

Thanks and regards.

Stef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following `hosts` inventory file

```
server1
server2
server3

[dev]
d1
d2
d3

[dev:vars]
ports=8080,8443

[int]
i1
i2
i3

[int:vars]
ports=80,443
```

and the following playbook `play.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    group: 'dev'

  tasks:
  - name: Just loop through a group and group_vars
    debug:
      msg: 'group is {{group}} target is {{item.0}} port is {{item.1}}'
    loop: >
      {{ groups[group] |
         product(hostvars[groups[group][0]]["ports"]) |
         list }}
```

you can loop through you inventory as you described

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml -l server* -e group=int
```

produces the following result:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Just loop through a group and group_vars] ********************************
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i1', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 80"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i1', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 443"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i1', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 80"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i1', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 443"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i2', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 80"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i1', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 80"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i2', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 443"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i1', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i1 port is 443"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i2', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 80"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i3', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 80"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i2', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 80"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i2', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 443"
}
ok: [server1] => (item=[u'i3', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 443"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i2', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i2 port is 443"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i3', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 80"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i3', 80]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 80"
}
ok: [server2] => (item=[u'i3', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 443"
}
ok: [server3] => (item=[u'i3', 443]) => {
    "msg": "group is int target is i3 port is 443"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server2                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server3                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You just have to replace the debug with the [wait_for module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/wait_for_module.html) for example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I knew that I had to use the "subelements" pattern but the key part is `hostvars[groups[group][0]]["ports"]`. With a little bit of tweak I will be able to separate the server list from that inventory, for example, by using add_host module and giving the server list as input parameter.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be nice ;-)

Comment: What if the var "group" is a list?

Comment: It would be best, if you ask this in a new question, because this has to do with standard looping.

Comment: Thanks, I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687709/ansible-nested-loops-through-inventories-plus-outer-loop-of-a-list).

Comment: @JGK - Can this be applied to hosts in different environments.  That is how can we use nested groups for /dev/qa/prod environment list of hosts in the inventory file.  e.g. kafka-broker: dev: server1 and qa:server2 and then run ansible on the dev hosts or qa hosts etc.

How can we define it in the yaml to select a specific environment group of hosts for a high level category?

Comment: Nested groups are explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821832/6561343 or in length in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/intro_inventory.html Limiting the execution could be done via the command line parameter `-l <SUBSET>, --limit <SUBSET>` A group can also be a subset.